# Прерывание на arduino

Tags: arduino

Имею arduino nano на ATmega 168P. Изучаю прерывание. Написал небольшой код

```
#define PIN_LED 8

volatile int actionState = LOW;

void setup()
{
  attachInterrupt(0, bb1, RISING);
  pinMode(PIN_LED, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(PIN_LED, actionState);
  delay(10);
}

void bb1()
{
  if (actionState == LOW)
  {
    actionState = HIGH;
  }
  else
  {
    actionState = LOW;
  }
}
```

Работает. Но есть проблема. Подвожу к пину 5V, диод загорелся. Отпускаю. Через пол секунды опять подвожу 5V, но диод не гаснет. Почему? Как часто можно вызывать прерывание?

Comment: К какому пину вы подводите 5?

Comment: По распиновке int0 это 2 порт - D2

Comment: 10 миллисекунд для прерывания, мне кажется, очень мало. Поставьте больше и все должно заработать.

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. Ваш код прекрасно работает и на Arduino Uno и на Arduino Mini. Если оставить пин, на который подвешено прерывание плавающим, то, разумеется, будет регистрироваться шум и прерывание будет возникать по совершенно случайным факторам (что будет видно и по светодиоду). Однако достаточно добавить pull-down резистор на пин, как все начинает работать так, как и должно. При желании можно воспроизвести дребезг контактов. Но никакого "но диод не гаснет" не получается. Все прекрасно включается и гаснет по команде.

Comment: В общем, показывайте детально, что именно вы там делаете. Дребезг контактов тут совершенно ни при чем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего вы забыли учесть такой фактор как дребезг контактов. Когда вы подводите питание 5V, то для вас это происходит довольно быстро. Но микроконтроллер, для которого одна секунда это целая вечность, успевает несколько раз обработать ваше прерывание. И в результате вы считаете, что прерывание не срабатывает, в то время как на самом деле, оно сработало четное количество раз.

Добавьте  delay(200) в обработчик прерывания, и все должно встать на свои места.

Comment: Нет. Дребезг контактов тут будет, но к сути вопроса он никакого отношения не имеет. Случайное количество срабатываний не может быть всегда *четным*.

Answer (score 3):

С частотой 32 Гц надо опрашивать кнопку, не чаще. Тогда контакт не будет дребезжать.

```
volatile bool stateChanged = false;

void bb1()
{
   stateChanged = true;
}

void loop()
{
   if (stateChanged) {
      digitalWrite(LED, actionState);
      actionState = (actionState == HIGH) ? LOW : HIGH;
      stateChanged = false;
   }
   delay(32);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Между кнопкой и землей необходимо поставить конденсатор 100nf для уменьшения помех, в т.ч. дребезга:

[image: https://radioprog.ru/uploads/media/articles/0001/02/42cf63c60189e07b6768ab9e4d038741e329301f.png]

Еще лучше сделать это через эмиттерный повторитель:

[image: https://www.ruselectronic.com/_files/200009492-1d5c01e564/%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C.JPG]